# How to set layout height fix in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created one layout in android. the issue I am facing is in some case there are two lines of description and in some cases there is only one line of description. and My layout height automatically adjust base on that. but I want to fix my layout height in every case. means my layout height should be equal in every case. Below is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notificationTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:textSize="18sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notificationDescription"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Description"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#f2f2f2" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notificationDealPrice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                            android:text="Deal Price"
                            android:textColor="#3691e9"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notificationActualPrice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/notificationDealPrice"
                            android:text="Actual Price"
                            android:background="@drawable/strike_thru"
                            android:textColor="#757575"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notificationDiscountPercentage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="10% OFF"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#f2f2f2" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="72"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Coupon Code" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notificationCouponCode"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Not Required"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="#308fe9"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#f2f2f2" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="72"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/notificationUrl"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="GET DEAL"
                            android:background="#78ca28"
                            android:textColor="#fff"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Image attached for the better understanding of the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soldA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the description TextView this attribute: `android:minLines="2"`